# API requests for ga:pageviews metric returns too less results

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, pageviews

I have a problem with the Google Analytics API.
I have two almost identical queries, the only difference is the selected metric ([ga:pageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pageviews) vs [ga:uniquePageviews](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_uniquepageviews))
the call for ga:pageviews return much lower totalResults than the call for uniquePageviews.

None of the queries use Sampling, so this should not be the Problem.

[image]

The otherwise identical Query with pageviews
[image]

At the bottom of the pictures you can see the total Results are much lower with the pageviews metric, but there shouldn't be any pagePaths that have uniquePageviews but no pageviews, so this data can't be accurate.

Am I missing something?
Can you help me get the correct numbers for the pageviews query?

Thanks!

Edit: Changing the date range or removing the filter does not resolve the problem

Edit2: after adding a sort by -ga:pageviews it looks like the results are grouped:
Hostname    Page    Pageviews
(other) (other) 204617

when I remove the hostname-dimension (and only use pagePath) this grouping does not occur and I get the complete list of URLs

I have no idea why the results are grouped, is there a way to prevent that?

Edit3: Looks like the results are thoses that have a session associated with them (Total results found: 1156 is the same number as a query for the ga:sessions metric returns) this only happens with pageviews (ga:uniquePageviews and also ga:hits returns all 200k+ rows)

Is this a bug or intended behaviour?

Comment: What happens when you do not pass any dimension?

Comment: uniquePageviews is session based and may have something to do with it.  It also counts both pagePath and pageTitle to determine uniqueness.

Comment: @dikesh In that case the results look much more accurate. I get a single result (439057 pageviews) when i set ga:pageviews as the only metric, 459439 pageviews + 405596 unique pageviews when I use both metrics and 405596 uniquePageviews if I only use that metric

Comment: I think @DalmTo 's comment is spot on - I get similar results in my accounts when I look at the last 7days, but the difference is smoothed out when I select a bigger timeframe. Looks like session-bases metrics have something to do with it.

Comment: Hmm... the numbers for uniquePageviews are the correct ones, the pageviews-counts are just too low when queried as the only metric. The Analytics Web-View also shows correct values (Where the pageviews are always higher (or at least as high) than uniquePageviews)

Comment: See edit2: after adding a sort by -ga:pageviews it looks like some of the results are grouped. I still have rows with only 1 or 2 pageviews, but some rows with a higher pageview number get removed/grouped to (other), so that is not the reason they dont appear as there own row

Comment: Edit3: Looks like the results are thoses that have a session associated with them (Total results found: 1156 is the same number as a query for the ga:sessions metric returns) this only happens with pageviews (ga:uniquePageviews and also ga:hits returns all 200k+ rows)

Comment: Have a look at definition of Unique Pageviews: "The number of unique page views. Page views within different sessions count as separate unique page views. This takes into account both the pagePath and pageTitle to determine uniqueness." May be this will give you some hint as you are taking pagepath as another dimension.

Comment: Probably because you included 'today' in your query with a 'unique' metric. I have noticed a lot of inconsistencies show up with those session-unique calculations on same-day.  e.g. Active Users for today sometimes show 2-3 times previous, and they drop to normal when I look back tomorrow.

Comment: I now have "solved" the problem by just adding the second metric ga:hits in addition to ga:pageviews (and ignoring those results). This deactivates the strange grouping behaviour and gives me the correct number of rows, just as ga:uniquePageviews does